# Why is Host Header not working

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have an intranet with an IIS 7.5 server that servers up a Default Web Site, and a second site which is bound with a host header of "orderentry".  This works fine.

Now I need a third site.  I set up a DNS record for it, and bind the site to "oepreprod"

When I test this new site, instead of going to the new site, it goes to the Default Web Site.  I cannot find a reason why this is not working as expected.

This is the binding that it shows in the site properties:

```
http:10.20.20.94:80:eopreprod
```

This is the request that is made to go to the site:

```
GET http://oepreprod/ HTTP/1.1
Host: oepreprod
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

As you can see, the header is properly set.

I don't know what else to try to get this to work.

I have tried restarting IIS, but it did not change anything.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your config is copy-pasted, the problem will be the difference between

```
eopreprod  (http:10.20.20.94:80:eopreprod)
```

and your request:

```
oepreprod  (Host: oepreprod)
```

To make it more visible:

## OE

vs

## EO

Comment: I am not following.  I set up the bindings using IIS Manager.  There was no copy-paste.  I don't understand `oepreprod  (Host: oepreprod)`  Where would that come from?

Comment: You wrote that your binding in the IIS config is for **eo**preprod, yet you try to connect to **oe**preprod. These are not the same...

Comment: Excellent, that must be the problem.  Will check it shortly and respond back.